# JS Uniquely identify nested objects properties

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a nested object like:

```
var nested = {
        k: 1,
        j: {
          i: 1,
          k: 0
        },
        o: function(a, bc) {},
        p: {
          k: 0,
          p: {
            py: 0,
            kg: 8
          }
        }
      }
```

And I try to loop it and generate a unique identifier from every property from `0 to n` where `n` is the total number of properties of the `var nested` object. Given the above `var nested` I expect something like:

```
var nested = {
            k: 1, -> (0)
            j: {  -> (1)
              i: 1, -> (2) 
              k: 0 -> (3)
            },
            o: function(a, bc) {}, -> (4)
            p: { -> (5)
              k: 0, -> (6)
              p: { -> (7)
                py: 0, -> (8)
                kg: 8 -> (9)
              }
            }
          }
```

If more simpler then I want to count how many properties does an (nested) object have and console.log every property and its index. I will update the question with a code prototype

Comment: What are expected results? Not really clear what you are trying to do ...or why? What is the use case for these identifiers? Also please show what you have tried

Comment: If more simpler then I want to count how many properties does an (nested) object have and `console.log` every property and its index. I will update the question with a code prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to iterate through nested objects/arrays.  You can either use the generated path that is passed to the callback as the unique identifier or you can iterate a counter in the callback as you go or coin whatever type of identifier you want.

```js
function iterateProperties(obj, fn, path) {
    var newPath, prop, i;
    path = path || "top";
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            newPath = path + "[" + i + "]";
            fn(newPath, obj[i]);
            if (typeof obj[i] === "object") {
                iterateProperties(obj[i], fn, newPath);
            }
        }
    } else {
        path += ".";
        for (prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                newPath = path + prop;
                fn(newPath, obj[prop]);
                if (typeof obj[prop] === "object") {
                    iterateProperties(obj[prop], fn, newPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


var nested = {
        k: 1,
        j: {
          i: 1,
          k: 0
        },
        o: function(a, bc) {},
        p: {
          k: 0,
          p: {
            py: 0,
            kg: 8
          }
        }
      }
      
iterateProperties(nested, function(path, val) {
    log(path, " = ", val);
}, "nested");
```

```html
<script src="http://files.the-friend-family.com/log.js"></script>
```

The one requirement of the object passed to this function is that it cannot have circular obj references.

Comment: An identifier like `nested.p.p.kg` works the best. Thank you! 
I was wondering what is the problem with the circular references?

Comment: @ValeriuMazare - Certain types of circular references (where child refers to parent) will cause an infinite loop which will eventually cause a stack overflow.  It's possible to protect against that with extra code.

Answer (score 1):

you can treat the properties like a properties tree.
root is nested
root: nested
2-level:(k,j,o,p)
     .....
then you can use [pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) to travel this properties tree.

you can visit the properties by using